# Cannot get value of text field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, jsp

I'm trying to write a code in JSP, using JQuery, to get credit card information and pass it to a servlet to process it. Following is my code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script
    src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">

</script>
<script>
    function dataValidation() {
        var cHolderName = $("#cardHolderName").val();
        var cCardNumber = $("#creditCardNumber").val();
        var eDate = $("#expirationDate").val();
        alert($("#cardHolderName").val());
        $.post("../CreditCard/CreditCardEvaluation", {
            cardHolderName : cHolderName,
            creditCardNumber : cCardNumber,
            expirationDate : eDate
        }, function(data, status) {

            if (data == 0) {
                alert("Invaid card data.");
            }

            if (data == 1) {

                $("result").text("Your order is placed.")
            }
        });
    }
</script>

</head>
<body>
    <form>
        Name of Card Holder:<input type="text" name="cardHolderName" value="Zahra"><br> 
        Credit Card Number:<input type="text" name="creditCardNumber" value="1-2-3-4"><br>
        Expiration Date:<input type="text" name="expirationDate" value="1/2/3">
        <input type="submit" onclick="dataValidation()"><br>
        <p id="result">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

In dataValidation function, I tried to show the card holder name, but it's null and it shows "undefined" message. Does any body know what the reason is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In:

```
var cHolderName = $("#cardHolderName").val();
var cCardNumber = $("#creditCardNumber").val();
var eDate = $("#expirationDate").val();
```

You are using ID selectors. So, change the `name` attributes to `id`s:

```
<form>
    Name of Card Holder:<input type="text" id="cardHolderName" value="Zahra"><br> 
    Credit Card Number:<input type="text" id="creditCardNumber" value="1-2-3-4"><br>
    Expiration Date:<input type="text" id="expirationDate" value="1/2/3">

    <input type="submit" onclick="dataValidation()"><br>
    <p id="result">
</form>
```

---

Alternatively, you can keep the `name` attributes and change the selectors instead:

```
var cHolderName = $("[name='cardHolderName']").val();
var cCardNumber = $("[name='creditCardNumber']").val();
var eDate = $("[name='expirationDate']").val();
```

But I'd recommend the first approach (changing to `id`s).